# Programmatically know whether a given path is network path or local path on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, filepath, core-foundation

How can I programmatically determine whether a given path is network path or local path on Mac OS X at run time?

Ex:
1. /Volumes/abc/xyz (mounted using smb)
2. ../test/pqr      (the application is on shared network path, hence the current working directory is also a network path and hence the relative path is also a network path)

Like on Windows below code will determine whether, pPath is a network shared path (like  * 1. \TallyDT100\c\test\file.txt 
2. z:\test\file.txt (A network path when z: is mapped to some network path).

```
    UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO   * universalname   = NULL;             ///< for getting the universal path name of file on network share.
    DWORD                   retval;                             ///< for getting the return value from WNetGetUniversalName
    DWORD                   length          = MAX_PATH_LEN;     ///< length of universal name which would be made.


// The memory for getting the universal name information is allocated.
universalname = (UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO *) Calloc (MAX_PATH_LEN * sizeof (Char));

retval = WNetGetUniversalName (pPath, UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, universalname, &length);

Free (universalname);

// NO_ERROR is returned only when it's drive mapped for shared network folder.
return (NO_ERROR == retval) ? true : false;
```

Comment: do you have specific network path??

Comment: Ex: 1. /Volumes/abc/xyz (mounted using smb)

Comment: Or 2. ../test/pqr (the application is on shared network path, hence the current working directory is also a network path and hence the relative path is also a network path)

Comment: Can i determine whether a given path is local or network depending on the filesystem ? may be using statfs and f_type to determine the filesystem and if the filesystems are NFS and SMB, then the path is network path? In that case how to determine the file system types?

Comment: Yes local path you can determine

Comment: By the way where is your local path present in your machine you can check that using NSFileManager

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone stumbles upon this from Google search, here is some useful information from Apple:

> There are numerous ways to test whether a volume is a network volume. The best method to use depends on the layer that you're working at:
>
> If you're working on general application code, you should use NSURL for this. Construct a URL for any item on the volume and then call -getResourceValue:forKey:error: to get the NSURLVolumeIsLocalKey key; the returned value will be false (kCFBooleanFalse) for a network volume and true (kCFBooleanTrue) for a local volume.
>
> If you're programming at the BSD layer, you can call statfs and test the MNT_LOCAL flag in the f_flags field that it returns. Alternatively, you can call getattrlist to request the ATTR_VOL_MOUNTFLAGS attribute, which can be more efficient than statfs under some circumstances.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/nw09/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DiskArbitration`

```
#import <DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration.h>

+(BOOL)isNetworkVolume: (NSURL *)volumeURL
{
    BOOL result = NO;
    int                 err = 0;
    DADiskRef           disk;
    DASessionRef        session;
    CFDictionaryRef     descDict;
    session = DASessionCreate(NULL);
    if (session == NULL) {
        err = EINVAL;
    }
    if (err == 0) {
        disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(NULL,session,(__bridge CFURLRef)volumeURL);
        if (session == NULL) {
            err = EINVAL;
        }
    }
    if (err == 0) {
        descDict = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
        if (descDict == NULL) {
            err = EINVAL;
        }
    }
    if (err == 0) {
        CFBooleanRef VolumeNetworkKey = CFDictionaryGetValue(descDict,kDADiskDescriptionVolumeNetworkKey);
        if (VolumeNetworkKey != NULL)
        {
            if (CFEqual(VolumeNetworkKey, kCFBooleanTrue)) {
                result = YES;
            }
        }
    }
    if (descDict != NULL) {
        CFRelease(descDict);
    }
    if (disk != NULL) {
        CFRelease(disk);
    }
    if (session != NULL) {
        CFRelease(session);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below how to detect whether your path exist on your machine or not:-

```
NSArray *arr=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *str=[arr lastObject];
NSString *yourPath=[str stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Volumes/abc/xyz"];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:yourPath])
{
    NSLog(@"This is your Local Path");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just one more doubt, this will return true for directories on Desktop of my user(/Users/XXX/Desktop/*) ONLY. It will return false for other directories (not on desktop) which are local to my system's hard disk.

Comment: No whatever path you will give, it determine accordingly. If you want to check for all directories then use NSDirectory class api

Answer (score 0):

You may use the NSLocalDomainMask and NSNetworkDomainMask in NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains.

For your reference the link - http://www.filibeto.org/unix/macos/lib/dev/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/LowLevelFileMgmt.pdf. The topic " Locating Directories on the System " here discusses the NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains class.